# How change project language in Travic CI?

Tags: docker, travis-ci

I use simple demo react app project and dcpkerize it .But Travic CI think that its ruby project and install ruby dependencies every commit. Why so?

travis.yml

```
sudo: required
services:
  - docker

before_install:
  - docker build -t axixa/docker-react -f Dockerfile.dev .

script:
  - docker run axixa/docker-react npm run test -- --coverage
```

test project linkg https://github.com/ahvahsky2008/docker-react

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `language: generic` at the top of your `.travis.yml` file.

And you do not need `services: [docker]` and probably not `sudo: required`.

This is how I am using it to test more complex apps:

```
# .travis.yml
language: generic

script:
- docker login -u $DOCKER_USER -p $DOCKER_PASS
- docker-compose build
- docker-compose run test
```

Seems like docker and docker-compose are a part of the base travis image.